# Page preloader loads to late

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

I use a custom CSS preloader which is loaded by following jQuery snippet.

The problem is that it loads together with javascript, so it takes a while. The result is, that for a first  2-3 seconds there is nothing on my page - no content and no preloader.

I tried to move my preloader script up in the project to loads it at first, but it doesn't help a lot.

How to make it to load immediately and without a lag?

```
<!-- Preloader -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $(window).load(function () { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
                $('#status').load("preloader/preloader.html"); // will first fade out the loading animation
                $('#preloader').delay(2500).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
                $('body').delay(2500).css({
                    'overflow': 'visible'
                });
            })
            //]]>
    </script>
```

preloader.html is a html code of my css preloader.

Comment: Where in your HTML is this script located?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your lag takes so long is because you are waiting for the whole site to be loaded. This is usually taken up by images, so replacing the `$(window).load` with `$(document).ready` will probably make it faster. Also notice your delay of 2500ms (2.5s), reducing that will make it load faster too.

```
<!-- Preloader -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
        $('#status').load("preloader/preloader.html", function() {
            //run after ajax get request completes (preloader.html is loaded)
            //now we remove the delays since we have explicity waited for the preloader to load
            $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
            $('body').css({
                'overflow': 'visible'
            });
        });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```